# Can anyone give me a list of invalid XML characters

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

Following is the bug:
http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-614

Above said bug, recommends us to use the resolution mentioned in the following link:
http://blog.lesc.se/2009/03/escape-illegal-characters-with-jaxb-xml.html

The resolution list 31 codes:

```
final String escapeString = "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005" +                
    "\u0006\u0007\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E\u000F\u0010\u0011\u0012" +            
    "\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001A\u001B\u001C" +               
    "\u001D\u001E\u001F\uFFFE\uFFFF";
```

Now, my question is, can I get the actual characters in ASCII for the above mentioned codes?

Answer (score 1):

None of those characters are printable.

Pasting that string in a Javascript console gives `"�"`.

Comment: ...and some of them don't even exist in ASCII (notably, `\uFFFE`, `\uFFFF`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store binary data in XML, it makes some sense to use e.g. Base64 encoding.
I don't think substituting them with the same "invalid" character is the best approach.

Comment: +1 I suspect, however, the issue is rogue XML files that have embedded characters that do not match the encoding declared at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a method that returns a `List<Character>` containing all of the invalid XML characters. This helped me with a unit test for a regular expression  that stripped these characters. You can view the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mriccid/bec0544de7d7b5b4b6009049d3abd27d)

In case the above link stops working, here is the code:

```
return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 65536).filter(XMLChar::isInvalid).mapToObj(c -> new Character((char) c))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

ASCII? No, ASCII goes up to 255. The entities 0x1F and below are all control characters.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
- http://www.ascii-code.com/
- If you want details on the Unicode/UTF-8 characters those represent, see any Unicode chart, like:

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: thanks for replying. Actually, my purpose was to display all the characters (invalid xml character list) which are invalid xml characters to the end user who is trying to input characters in an textbox and before trying to save it to xml.

Comment: Actually, ASCII only goes up to 127.

Comment: @MichaelKay I was giving the benefit of the extended, 8-bit, ISO 8859-1 doubt, but you're correct, ASCII is 7-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Search google for "java unicode". Example result as follows:

http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html

Unicode is designed to cover all character sets. The original "ASCII" was only good for North America. Java itself has unicode support built it, but there are still lots of character encoding "gotchas" to discover :-)

Answer (score 0):

The official list of *allowed* characters in an XML document is defined as follows:

```
Char       ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] |
[#x10000-#x10FFFF]  /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate
blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
```

However, in addition to that definition the XML Recommendation also suggests *avoiding* what it terms "compatibility characters" which it defines as follows:

```
[#x7F-#x84], [#x86-#x9F], [#xFDD0-#xFDEF],
[#x1FFFE-#x1FFFF], [#x2FFFE-#x2FFFF], [#x3FFFE-#x3FFFF],
[#x4FFFE-#x4FFFF], [#x5FFFE-#x5FFFF], [#x6FFFE-#x6FFFF],
[#x7FFFE-#x7FFFF], [#x8FFFE-#x8FFFF], [#x9FFFE-#x9FFFF],
[#xAFFFE-#xAFFFF], [#xBFFFE-#xBFFFF], [#xCFFFE-#xCFFFF],
[#xDFFFE-#xDFFFF], [#xEFFFE-#xEFFFF], [#xFFFFE-#xFFFFF],
[#x10FFFE-#x10FFFF].
```

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets